# JavaFX Round image using SceneBuilder(with Clip)

Tags: java, javafx

> In the code it is pretty easy:

```
   // Clip
   Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(168, 168);
   rect.setArcHeight(30);
   rect.setArcWidth(30);
   rect.setEffect(new Reflection());
   imageView.setClip(rect);  //where imageView is an ImageView
```

> I am trying to do it using  `SceneBuilder` but i don't know
>   how..Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If i well understood you are trying to populate a node (like a box or box or a pane or whatever you want)with your object rectangle, i think it's not possible doing it from the Scene Builder, you must do it from the code.
If you want to do it you have add it to a subScene i think!

```
PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera();
ImageView imageview = new ImageView();

Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(168, 168);
rect.setArcHeight(30);
rect.setArcWidth(30);
rect.setEffect(new Reflection());

imageview.setClip(rect);
Group g = new Group(imageview);
SubScene subSceneInsertion = new SubScene(g, 919, 600, true, SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED);
subSceneInsertion.setFill(Color.DARKSLATEGREY);//yourcolour
subSceneInsertion.setCamera(camera);
Group groupForSubScene = new Group(subSceneInsertion);
groupForSubScene.autoSizeChildrenProperty().setValue(Boolean.TRUE);
groupForSubScene.setAutoSizeChildren(true);                
hBoxForRectangle.getChildren().add(groupForSubScene);
```

Comment: From 5 lines of code we got to 17 lines of code.Why i need to use a SubScene?How that can solve the problem?I mean i have to write both code and both fxml..Also mention that `SceneAntialising` is not needed for 2D Shapes.